# SQL Left Join not returning "0" or null

Tags: sql, syntax

I am trying to get a count of all open positions, the "paposition" table holds all available positions, the "employee" table holds all employees in that position. When I run the statement below I receive

```
Department     Job Code     Count(*)

10             2            1

10             1            1
```

but I'm expecting this; because there are currently no employees in Job Code "3'

```
Department     Job Code     Count(*)

10             3            0

10             2            1

10             1            1
```

How can I get the count for Job Code 3 to show as "0" or "null" is also acceptable

```
select pos.department, pos.job_code, count(*)
from paposition pos
left join employee emp
on (pos.department = emp.department
and pos.job_code = emp.job_code)
where pos.job_code in ('1', '2', '3')
and pos.end_date = '01-Jan-1700'
and (emp.emp_status like 'A%'
or emp.emp_status like 'L%')
and emp.department = '0010'
group by pos.department, pos.job_code
order by pos.department, pos.job_code
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are undoing the `left outer join` by including columns from `emp` in the `where` clause.

You need to move the conditions to the `on` clause:

```
select pos.department, pos.job_code, count(*)
from paposition pos left join
     employee emp
     on (pos.department = emp.department and
        pos.job_code = emp.job_code and
        (emp.emp_status like 'A%' or emp.emp_status like 'L%') and emp.department = '0010'
where pos.job_code in ('1', '2', '3') and
      pos.end_date = '01-Jan-1700' and
group by pos.department, pos.job_code
order by pos.department, pos.job_code;
```

(Or, alternatively, you could check for `NULL` being a valid value in the `where` clause for `emp.emp_status` and `emp.department`.)

Comment: This casues every department to have a count of 1